# Do the seat rows across the aisle from the Cathay Pacific 777 300 ER 77H aircraft line up?

Tags: airlines, seating, cathay-pacific

The economy rows in the picture on seat guru do not appear to line up with each other. For example  do 60G and 60H line up next to each other. I want two aisle seats that are directly across from each other.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the picture, and perhaps a link to the site?

Comment: It is quite common on twin-aisle aircraft for the central seats not to line up with the outer ones, to take into account the position of the various “obstacles”. What is your point? There’s an aisle between those seats anyway...

Comment: @jcaron Not the OP, but one example why you'd need to know: if you're traveling with more than two kids, it's useful to line up the whole family in a row to keep them under control.

Answer (score 13):

[Here is the official Cathay Pacific seating map](https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_HK/travel-information/flying-with-us/aircraft-and-fleet/boeing-777/300.html) (pick 77H from the dropdown, there are multiple different models).  As you can see, seats do not line up across the aisles, although the gap is slightly less pronounced towards the front of the each economy cabin section (near rows 40 and 60).

Answer (score 7):

In many planes, the rows simple *do not* line up. Chances are that Seatguru shows you the correct physical layout.

Answer (score 7):

> I want two aisle seats that are **directly** across from each other.

Impossible.

As you can see in that seat map of the triple seven 300 77H:

[image]

every pair or rows doesn't directly line up to each other.

If you interested in an approximation, then I'd suggest you to check the rows 68-72, which are located towards the tail of the aircraft. Personally, I would go for 69, if I was you.

At that section, the cabin gets narrower, thus the distance between the rows is smaller (which might be a good thing, if for example you intend talking to the person at the other side), in respect to the distance between the rows closer to the center.

Comment: I would go for 69 as well.

Comment: What's the source of the seat map?